# Docker installation just downloads index.html file

Tags: docker, ubuntu-12.04

Following these instructions:

[Ubuntu installation](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/)

on Ubuntu Server 12.04. I've set my https_proxy in /etc/environment. Next I do:

```
sudo wget https://get.docker.com/
```

and the response is "cannot verify get.docker.com's certificate... to connect insecurely use '--no-check-certificate'.

So I do:

```
sudo wget --no-check-certificate https://get.docker.com/
```

I'm still getting a message complaining "cannot verify get.docker.com's certificate" and wget downloads the index.html file from get.docker.com rather than an installation package.

I am very new to Linux - please can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Might be something to do with the fact you specified a https_proxy. Is that actually necessary?

Comment: Thought (perhaps incorrectly) that wget from a https:// site required the https proxy setting. If I just set a http_proxy in /etc/environment then the connection times out.

Comment: Do you definitely need any proxy at all? If so, then maybe you do need to use the `https_proxy` var. However, I've just been there and seen it works over http anyway. Have you checked the contents of the html file? Just because it saved with that extension doesn't necessarily mean it actually contains html

Comment: Definitely have to go through the company proxy. The first lines of the index.html file say "This script is meant for quick and easy install via..." and then it lists the wget I ran and a curl alternative (this doesn't work either). So it is a list of instructions for linux to follow but it's not following them.

Comment: So then it isn't a `html` file - it is a shell script as I can see that content. As an alternative that might get round this, have you tried doing `sudo apt-get install docker.io`?

Comment: Tried that but I get "unable to locate package docker.io". So tried just docker and it did install something. But now if I run 'sudo docker run hello-world' I get 'Segmentation Fault or Critical Error encountered. Dumping core and aborting'.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this:

```
sudo wget https://get.docker.com/
```

The instructions to which you linked tell you to do this:

```
wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

That retrieves the shell script and pipes it to the shell for execution.  For the record I am morally opposed to this sort of installation, but that's what you need to do to follow those instructions.

Comment: Tried this; I get no response. Cursor sits flashing and that's it.

Comment: Why "morally opposed"?

Comment: @markp3rry It's an extremely dangerous practice and I actually can't believe there are so many companies advocating installation in this fashion. Essentially you're allowing a resource that you have no understanding of to go about installing whatever it fancies on your machine. Add a `sudo` to that command and it'll have unrestricted access to your entire system.